# Duplex printing gives punched holes in wrong place

Tags: printing, duplex-printing

When I print single sided, the punched holes (on A4) show up on the correct side of the documents.

When I print duplex, the punched holes end up on the wrong side.  (They should be on the left side if looking at the first page.)

I understand there should be some kind of CUPS setting to make duplex printing use the correct orientation, but I can't find where it is.

(This problem is to many/most duplex capable printers and not Linux specific btw, but I can't find in Ubuntu the setting.)

The option to actually go to the printer and turn the pages physically is not acceptable, since I share office with co-workers who print non-duplex.

Comment: How to solve in OSX http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Mac-Printing-and-Scanning/Duplex-printing-paper-holes-appears-on-wrong-side/td-p/1098839

Answer (score 3):

Found it.

Go to printer Printers, choose Printer Properties,
select ***Job Options*** and change *Orientation:* from ***Portrait*** to ***Reverse portrait*** (180 degrees).